# javaFx application extension

Tags: java

i a beginner at java and I'm trying to compile 2 java codes Account.java and AccounTest.java and the command prompt keeps giving this message
"Main method not found in class Account, please define main method or a javaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application"
researched on javafx apication and none was specific on what and where i should import. here is Account.java
    "public class Account
     private double balance;

```
public Account( double initialBalance )
{


if (initialBalance > 0.0)
        balance = initialBalance;
} 

    public void credit( double amount)
{
    balance = balance + amount; 
}

    public double getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have a main method.